# How can I use various applications like Monokle, and Lens when I am using WSL2 (using ubuntu) and minikube is installed in ubuntu?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kubectl, wsl-2

The applications do not recognize the running clusters. I have installed docker desktop in windows. How can I solve this problem?

I tried to add the config path "\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\.....\config" but it does not work

Comment: Do you get some output or any error message?